# External monitor turns off after 15 minutes - when machine is being used

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

One of the users in my company has a Dell XPS13 laptop, with an external monitor connected via a USB > VGA cable. After around 15 minutes of the laptop being used, the video on the external screen cuts out and the monitor goes into standby. The screen on the laptop stays on. The power setting is to "do nothing when lid is closed" so the second screen stays on when the laptop lid is closed.

The issue can be resoved by unplugging the USB > VGA converter but this is not a desired behaviour of a £1000 machine.

I have:

- Swapped the screen out with a spare
- Updated the graphics drivers for the USB video adaptor and the Intel Graphics Driver
- Swapped the VGA cable
- Tried using the Mini Displayport to output to the screen (Mini Displayport > DVI cable) - screen does not turn on at all.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to visit the monitor's settings.  The monitor control panel might have a setting to disable powersave mode.  The monitor has settings for things like adjusting the settings on the monitor itself.

There is a button on the laptop that allows you to toggle the screen.  That is, you could run the laptop with the screen as the primary monitor.  Did you look at whether the screen option has two monitors in the control panel settings.

Comment: The external monitor is set up as the primary screen, and the display mode is set to duplicate so the two monitors appear as 1|2 in the control panel options. There doesn't seem to be any options for timeout on the screen (I have one of the same model connected to my desktop)